# Error Message "MySQL server has gone away" when running an UPDATE query

Tags: php, mysqli

I run a php file on a cron job that runs every minute, with a loop that lasts 60 seconds. Before the loop starts, I connect to the database with `mysqli`. Then I begin the loop. The first query gets a list of users, then a query is done on each list item from that first query. After all updates on items have been done, the outer loop sleeps for 3 seconds before repeating.

The problem is that the inner loop's query always returns the error "MySQL server has gone away". This just started a few days ago, after working fine for weeks, and there has been no changes to the code. If I copy the exact query that gives me the error, then go into phpMyAdmin and paste it in, it updates successfully with no error.

The outer loop's query works every loop.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($SQL_data["domain"], $SQL_data["user"], $SQL_data["password"], $SQL_data["database"]);
$start_time =  time();
while((time() - $start_time) < 60)
{
    $stream_list = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM {$SQL_data[table]} WHERE -- Blah Blah...");
    $number_of_results = $stream_list->num_rows;
    // Operates on each result from the SQL call
    for($i = 1; $i <= $number_of_results; $i++)
    {
        //some if statements and switches

        // The query that returns the error "MySQL server has gone away"
        $mysqli->query("UPDATE {$SQL_data[table]} SET online=1, lastUpdate = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), displayName = '$displayName' WHERE username='".$row["username"]."'");
    }// for($i = 1; $i <= $number_of_results; $i++)

}// while((time() - $start_time) < 60)
```

Information about the databse:

- Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
- Server type: MySQL
- Server version: 5.5.32-cll-lve - MySQL Community Server (GPL)

I do not know if there was any update or changes to it recently, I pay for hosting from a web hosting company.

Comment: the server is timing out. hence it closes the connection. check [**this**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gone-away.html)

Comment: How would it timeout if it's connecting to localhost, and the time between queries is less than 1 second?

Comment: the message clearly saying it has time out. check the configs for more detail.

Comment: How would I check if there was a timeout? Because all the configs have timeouts of 10 seconds or greater, and I used `ini_set('mysql.connect_timeout', 300);`
`ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 300);`

Answer (score 2):

"server has gone away" is the error that MySql returns when the client has been disconnected from the server.
It happens in your case when the internet connection is probably not stable

otherwise try to increase the timeout:

```
ini_set('mysql.connect_timeout', 300);
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 300);
```

Comment: Is the application (web browser) that you are testing on the same server or in a local network?

Comment: The script is on the same server. Also the timeout settings that you have specified are already in the script. The time between script executions is usually less than 1 second.

Comment: Another option you would look after is the `max_allowed_packet`, if the amount of query is higher than this value, you will also see this error once again. The default value is set to 1MB.
Looking at your query `SELECT * FROM`, probably the result could be bigger than 1MB

Comment: The `max_allowed_packet` is 268,435,456, while the timeouts are all 10 or higher, except for `innodb lock wait timeout` which is 1. The SELECT query is right now getting 5 entries.